# How do I alter environment variables for Lambda function based on a schedule?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I have a function on AWS Lambda that I have a couple of environment variables for. Some of them, like `userID` need to be changed depending upon what schedule it is. I think the best approach is to create separate `EventBridge` rules for each user, but that approach does not scale well. Is there a way I could make something on AWS (like a file with user IDs and their associated times), which a function reads and then passes on to a scheduler?

Comment: I know this is a classic SO non-answer, but maybe ENV variable is not the best tool for this job? If I needed something like this I'd probably store it in dynamodb with the timeframe as a key and userId as a value. If you really want to change the env variable I guess you could do it through terraform / cloudformation / serverless framework and run a cronjob that applies it. but really I'd reconsider the approach in your case.

Comment: can you not use s3 and create a private bucket with these userid mapping?  from your function you could then get the file and do the needful.

Comment: What triggers the Lambda to be invoked? Can that supply the event data you need?